# Get time difference in hours

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the hours difference from current time to start date in hours?

```
var diff = new Date("2016-02-26 17:21:29") - new Date();
diff_time = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
//alert(diff_time);

if (diff_time < 24) {
    alert("Please select the start date greater than 24 hours");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time format should be `/` or space separated, not `-` separated

```
var diff = new Date($('#start_date').val()) - new Date() ;
diff_time = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
alert(diff_time);
return false;

if (diff_time < 24) {
    error = "Please select the start date on";
}
```